# Contested Territory on iOS Bloons City

Tags: bloons-monkey-city

Is the contested territory feature that's on the PC version of Bloons Monkey City also in the iOS version?

Comment: By Bloons City, do you mean Bloons Monkey City?

Comment: Yes sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the contested territory feature is also available in the iOS version, however you need to be connected to a network (wifi or cellular data) for it to work.

Source: I captured the contested territory in the ios version of the game 30 minutes ago.